# How is this an unhandled promise rejection inside a try catch block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, promise

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    !user && res.status(401).json("Invalid credentials!");

    const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      user.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    );

    const originalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    originalPassword !== req.body.password &&
      res.status(401).json("Invalid credentials!");

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;

    res.status(200).json(others);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error.message);
  }
});
```

When I post an incorrect username or an incorrect password I do get the **correct** HTTP Response `Invalid Credentials!`

However I receive an unhandled promise rejection error in my console log.

> (node:12080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
> at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\dinin\Projects\testexpress2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
> at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\dinin\Projects\testexpress2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
> at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\dinin\Projects\testexpress2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
> at C:\Users\dinin\Projects\testexpress2\routes\auth.js:24:21
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> (node:12080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)

It's obviously in a try catch block. How can I "handle" this promise properly?

Comment: You can't response a http request twice...

Comment: use just a normal if statement for `originalPassword !== req.body.password`, and `!user && ` check and return... or throw an error and let the catch pick it up, might as well use it

Comment: also, you should utilise `next()` and pass the caught error to the error middleware instead of res'ing inside the middleware, then none of your middlewares needs to handle anything more than good responses and the error handler can do much more then just respond like, log or change the response content-type based upon accept headers, or if xhr etc

Comment: You send a response twice: `res.status(401).json("Invalid credentials!")` & `res.status(200).json(others);`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks Lawrence, instead of res'ing I'm throwing an error and letting the catch pick it up. I am definitely going to look into using an error middleware :)